# Sorting arrays using their ratio

Tags: c, sorting

I need some help to make a function that would sort 2 arrays by

1 - finding the value of : ratio = array1[]/array2[]

2 - sorting the result and to sort the 2 arrays depending on the result we got

3 - make it so the change happens on the array i've put in argument

This is how i tried to do it, but i'm getting as an error :

```
    ||=== Build: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\Amine\Desktop\Knapsack\test\main.c||In function 'main':|
C:\Users\Amine\Desktop\Knapsack\test\main.c|40|warning: passing argument 1 of 'triVariable' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|
C:\Users\Amine\Desktop\Knapsack\test\main.c|7|note: expected 'int **' but argument is of type 'int (*)[4]'|
C:\Users\Amine\Desktop\Knapsack\test\main.c|40|warning: passing argument 2 of 'triVariable' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|
C:\Users\Amine\Desktop\Knapsack\test\main.c|7|note: expected 'int **' but argument is of type 'int (*)[4]'|
||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
||=== Run: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
```

and i can't seem to find a solution to it.

```
void triVariable(int **a, int **c, int n){
    int i, j, temp, tempa, tempc;
    int *ratio = malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        ratio[i]= (*c)[i] / (*a)[i];
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++) { 
        for(j=i+1;j<n; j++) {
            if(ratio[j]<ratio[i]) {
                temp=ratio[i];
                ratio[i]= ratio[j];
                ratio[j]= temp;

                tempa=(*a)[i];
                (*a)[i]=(*a)[j];
                (*a)[j]=tempa;

                tempc=(*c)[i];
                (*c)[i]=(*c)[j];
                (*c)[j]=tempc;

            }
        }


    }
}

int main(){
    int n=5;
    int c[]={12,8,2,5};
    int a[]={5,4,1,3};

    triVariable(&a, &c, n);

    printf("C : ( ");
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("%d ", c[i]);
    }
    printf(")\n");
    printf("A : ( ");
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf(")\n");
}
```

If anyone could point out something i'm missing that would be great !

Comment: A pointer to an array is not the same thing as a pointer to a pointer. And there's no need to pass a pointer to the arrays, as arrays naturally decays to pointers (to their first element). That is, if you pass e.g. `a` when a `int *` is expected, what is automatically passed is `&a[0]`.

Comment: And note that you have a memory leak, as you never pass `ratio` to `free`. There's no need to allocate it dynamically in the first place, since C (since the C99 standard) allows *variable-length arrays*. So plain `int ratio[n];` will work fine, and not have any leaks.

Comment: Lastly, you *will* go out of bounds of the arrays `a` and `c`. You iterate over *five* elements, but `a` and `c` only have *four*. That of course leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I corrected my code for the last 2 comments, but i need some clarification on the first one. i still have some big issues with understanding how pointers work so i tried to apply things that worked on a previous program i wrote in this case and it didn't go as planned. basically i used **a and **c because i expect that's the only way to change my arrays through the function, and i used *a[i] *c[i] everytime i used them on the function because that's how i don't get errors when compiling. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am so dumb, i just got it ! Thanks so much :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @someprogrammerdude i managed to correct my code !

```
void triVariable(int *a, int *c, int n){
    int i, j, temp, tempa, tempc;
    int ratio[n];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        ratio[i]= (c)[i] / (a)[i];
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++) { //On met à jour notre liste d'objets pour qu'elle soit trier du plus grand ratio au plus petit
        for(j=i+1;j<n; j++) {
            if(ratio[j]<ratio[i]) {
                temp=ratio[i];
                ratio[i]= ratio[j];
                ratio[j]= temp;

                tempa=(a)[i];
                (a)[i]=(a)[j];
                (a)[j]=tempa;

                tempc=(c)[i];
                (c)[i]=(c)[j];
                (c)[j]=tempc;

            }
        }
    }
    free(ratio);
}

int main(){
int n=4;
int c[]={12,8,2,5};
int a[]={5,4,1,3};

triVariable(&a[0], &c[0], n);

printf("C : ( ");
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
printf("%d ", c[i]);
}
printf(")\n");
printf("A : ( ");
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
printf(")\n");
}
```